# specifying from/to in seq.POSIXt

Tags: r, xts

I'm writing a function which does some data pre-processing, and one of the things I'm doing is creating a regularly spaced xts object.  All of the examples I've seen use `seq.POSIXt` in a way similar to this:

```
temp <- xts(, seq.POSIXt(from = start(data), to = end(data), by = 0.001)
data <- cbind(temp, data)
data <- data["T08:30:00.001/T15:00:00"]
```

Is there a way to specify the from/to directly as a time of day **without specifying a date**?  I'm wasting a lot of time by cbinding to "temp" when temp usually begins at 0:00:00 and ends at 11:59:59, and then cutting the result to 8:30:00.001 to 15:00:00.  I'd much prefer the temp to start at 8:30:00.001 and end at 15:00:00, if that's possible.

Comment: What is the structure of `data` (e.g. `str(data)`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not *as the sequence is over `POSIXt` types* and you cannot have a date + time type without an underlying date.

You can of course write yourself a helper function which just injects a given, or randomly chosen, date and then does the magic *once a complete time object has been formed*.

Note that `xts` too will need a correct `POSIXt` object.